# Is `&variable = null;` possible?

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax

If you set a pointer to null, the variable is deleted. It can't be used anymore and it won't take your storage anymore.
And the name for the pointer represents its value. Its value is always `&someVariable`.
So could I do this: `&someVariable = null;`

[EDIT] I was very new to C++ when I wrote this, so I had multiple misconceptions.

To delete a pointer, you must `delete ptr;` instead of setting it to null via `ptr = nullptr;`.

`&someVariable` is an rvalue, so it can't get anything assigned.

It's `0`, `NULL` or `nullptr`, not `null`.

In summary, you should never `delete &anything;`, even if you're lucky and it compiles. Just delete the pointer you got when allocating `anything`.

Comment: Did you try? It shouldn't take more than 5 minutes to whip up some sample code

Comment: Also: *"If you set a pointer to null, the variable is deleted"* - no, nothing is deleted in C++ if you set a pointer to null

Comment: I asked google but forgot to try. And how do you delete variables then? SoloLearn told me you had to set the pointer to null. That app must be written by a drunken teddy bear.

Comment: _"And how do you delete variables then?"_. In reality you want to use smart pointers and RAII and don't delete anything manually, but technically answer is: _by using `delete`_

Comment: You don't delete variables - variables are a compile time construct (and there would be no point to deleting them either). Setting a pointer to null only makes that pointer point to null, nothing else. The only thing you `delete` in C++ is dynamically allocated memory (allocated using `new`)

Comment: Thank you. Why wouldn't there be a point to deleting them? It's less memory.

Comment: you aren't deleting a variable, you are deleting dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: Ok, so does this work?

Comment: `int x = new int[5]; delete x;`

Comment: For that you would want to use `delete [] x;` if you call new with [] you delete with [], if you call new without brackets you delete without brackets.

Comment: I don't know what SoloLearn is but don't try to learn C++ from a random app on your mobile phone. Get [a proper, peer-reviewed book written by someone who actually knows what they're talking about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Ok. I'm learning on another tutorial than SoloLearn, but I want to start my project. Hope I'll make less drastic fales when I progress.

Comment: No, not a tutorial. A book. A proper, paper book.

Comment: learncplusplus.com seems to be good. they don't tell you you can learn it fast and have many examples.

Comment: Did you mean `Java`?

Comment: Why Java? What do you mean? Java was my first language, yes...

Comment: The behavior you describe sounds like `Java`.

Comment: Sorry, wrong spelling of the website: It's called `learncpp.com`.

Comment: Java was my first programming language, so I try to figure out how a new language works with what I've already learned about it and `Java`.

Comment: No offence but you are not qualified to determine whether it is good or not :) (Although at first glance that one looks a lot better than most)

Comment: I'm not able to determine if it explains the C++ questions well, but I'm able to rate the style as I'm not such a noob in Java. But you're right, I can't determine if it's good. That's why I wrote that it seems to be good. I knew I couldn't determine that.

Comment: Let's see who's drunk.  I also use **SoloLearn** to learn C++ and their courses are pretty good.  I don't know where you read that but what their course says is `"for local variables on the stack, managing memory is carried out automatically.
On the heap, it's necessary to **manually** handle the dynamically allocated memory, and use the **delete** operator to free up the memory when it's no longer needed".`

Comment: That's pretty embarassing. I shouldn't write so late at night. Apologies to the SoloLearn team.

Comment: I usually check my sources and write in a neutral and friendly tone, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you set a pointer to null, the variable is deleted.

No, it isn't.

> It can't be used anymore and it won't take your storage anymore.

That is not true.

> So could I do this: `&someVariable = null;`

No. Even if you wrote `nullptr` instead of the non-existent `null`, and even if you could modify an rvalue of built-in type, it would only set the value of some *temporary* pointer to `nullptr`.

**Modifying a pointer has absolutely no effect on the thing it used to point to.**

It sounds like you have become confused regarding `delete` and setting pointers to null.

Comment: What about an overloaded `operator&()`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: You cannot overload `operator&` on a built-in type.

Comment: Where in the question is it mentioned that `someVariable` is a built-in type?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It isn't; rather, that was a premise of that particular part of my answer. It is possible to create an extraordinarily convoluted design that somehow allowed the given statement to have the expected effect. However, I am reasonably certain we can rule out that possibility in this case.

Answer (score 7):

No you can't. `&someVariable` is an rvalue. It cannot be assigned to and it is meaningless to try.

Furthermore, the very idea of what you are trying to do is meaningless. Function variables are allocated on the stack and are only freed when the function returns. Global variables can't be freed. Variables within allocated structures can't possibly be freed has the heap doesn't work that way.

Variables don't get deleted. That is meaningless. Memory gets deallocated depending on how it was allocated:

- on stack -> function return
- allocated with `new` -> `delete` or `auto_ptr` or other smart pointer (which calls `delete`)
- allocated with `malloc` -> `free`
- global variable -> process exit

Comment: I think you meant it is a prvalue.

Comment: So pointers work just for global variables?

Comment: @JamesRoot: Turns out I meant rvalue. :( No point in going into the fine differences now.

Comment: @TimonPaßlick: Pointers work just fine for any variable.

Comment: _"Variables don't get deleted. That is meaningless."_ Well, no, it isn't. Placement and non-placement new/delete make that clear, in that you can control object lifetime when the language isn't doing so for you.

Comment: `auto_ptr` has been deprecated for many years now. Perhaps you could use `shared_ptr` as an example instead.